# Error al intentar instalar composer en Mac Os Catalina

Tags: php, composer

Por alguna razon cada vez que intento instalar composer me sale "Illegal Instruction: 4" y se cancela la instalación

Answer (score 0):

Significa que el instalador está compilado pa versiones anteriores y ya no funciona en esa versión de OSX.

De hecho, hay un issue [reportado](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6494) al respecto. Posiblemente debas instalar de nuevo PHP, de acuerdo a lo que dicen allí.

Comment: Use brew uninstall php y todo correcto, lo volvi a instalar pero esta vez desde la pagina de composer, pero igualmente me sigue saliendo el mismo error.